# sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection - when will support http method PATCH?

Tags: patch

I fail to use sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection (JDK v6, and also v7) when trying to send PATCH requests. It happens in getOutputStream() methid, in which there is a validation check that validates only POST or PUT methods are allowed. But what about PATCH? it should be valid too.

Can someone tell when this will be available?

Can someone tell what can I do instead? Any other kind of Java library?

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK HttpURLConnection doesn't support the HTTP PATCH method in JDK6, JDK7 nor JDK8.
No official JDK roadmap shows this item for the moment.

You can use [Apache HTTPClient 4.2+](https://hc.apache.org/) or [AsyncHTTPClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).